# MySQL database offline for debugging purposes?

Tags: php, mysql, database, debugging, offline

I want to debug my PHP program, but it only debugs if the files are offline in the C:/user/local/temp/appdata etc. So I downloaded the whole website onto my computer, but I can't get it to access the database. The MySQL database is built into the website.

How can I access the MySQL? I desperately need to debug this program.

Comment: what you mean that the database is built into the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'll want to create an environment that is almost identical to production (using VMWare or some other VM solution). However, if you're strapped for time, you could connect directly to the remote mysql instance.

MySQL, by default, doesn't listen on any external IPs. So if you want to connect to it, you'll need to modify the MySQL instance on the server to listen on the external IP.

To check it, connect to the server via SSH as root and run:

```
netstat -nlp | grep mysqld
```

This will list all of the programs and the ports that they're listening on. For example

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      818/mysqld
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3777     818/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

This means that mysql is only running on 127.0.0.1 (which is not a localhost IP) on port 3306.

You'll need to modify /etc/my.conf or /etc/mysqld/my.cnf and edit:

```
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

Listen on all interfaces.

Then restart mysqld:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Now you should be able to confirm that mysqld is listening on the external IP with netstat and you should be able to connect to it from your remote computer.

HTH

Comment: PS. Recommend you put your code in source control (git) and create a VM with its own MySQL instance. Only run scripts (that are in source control) to manipulate the production database. That is, unless you like pulling out your hair.

Comment: Another alternative to setting up your own VM is to get a free micro instance from Amazon (for 1 year).  You can install mysqld on the instance and have a nice debugging server for a while.  See http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Comment: oh no way man. I just created a mock set of data to serve as a placeholder for the actual database. my god. git, VM source control, micro instance, amazon?

Comment: If you're not using source control now, you'd be well advised to start using it before you start debugging (and, I presume, changing) your code. Good source control systems are free, even on Windows. The Cygwin project offers RCS, git, mercurial, and subversion at the very least.

Comment: I do not have the brain capacity to start using Source control yet, but I will say that I simply made a "mock-up" database which I just substituted for off-line debugging.